# How to upload an object data type to your document in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of structs which looks like:

```swift
struct ChocolateToAppend{
  var Brand: String
  var Chocolate: String
  var ChocolateCalories: String
}
```

```swift
var ChocolatesArray = [ChocolateToAppend]()
```

I populate the array filled with structs so it contains many elements in the array.

How can I convert this array of structs into an upload of object data type for Firestore using the .addDocument? I understand and can easily upload data and documents into Firestore but I am struggling with how to convert or map the array containing structs into the object data type for the document. I know I would need it to end up looking something like:

```swift
chocRef.addDocument(data: ["Chocolates": ["Cadbury":["Wispa":467, "DoubleDecker":563], 
                                          "Lindt":["Milk":"73", "Strawberry Cream": 132],
                                          "Nestle": ["Galaxy": 43, "Milkyway": 342]]
```

How can I get the array of data to look like the above to upload?

Comment: Can we assume you know how to write one object and are asking how to write the entire array of objects? What's wrong with iterating over the array to write each object? Also note that in your `.addDocument` function, you're using the Brand as the key (documentId) of each document and that's probably not a good idea. Better to let Firestore create the documentId and keep the brand as a field (hint: documentId's are unique so you could only ever have one Cadbury document otherwise)